# SwipeRefreshLayout with fixed header

Tags: android, android-listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have the sequent layout:

```
<com.example.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.example.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

with fixed header and a scrollable list. CustmoSwipeRefreshLayout is a class that extends SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
private ListView childListView;

public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setChildListView(ListView childListView) {
    this.childListView = childListView;
}

@Override
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
    return childListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() != 0;
}
```

(where childListView is the widget with id lv). This code doesn't work as i want. In fact, progress circle appear in two cases:
- i swipe listview to top
- i make swipe gesture on header and listview has first element visible.

I would that progress circle appear both if i swipe listview to top (as works now), and also if i make swipe gesture on header and listview is not to top element

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was set `android:clickable="true"` inside my parent layout. try it like this:

```
<com.example.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:clickable="true" <!-- this line -->
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/header_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.example.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Circle appear only if swipe happen when listview has first element visible